# Populating a react-table with an object instead of a list

Tags: javascript, react-table

The documentation for the react-table library (https://github.com/react-tools/react-table#data) states:

> "Simply pass the data prop anything that resembles an array or object."

However, the tables are rendered as expected when passing in an array of data, but when passing an object, I get the error:

> "Invalid prop `data` of type `object` supplied to `ReactTable`, expected `array`."

An example data object looks like this:

```
const data = {
"entry1": {
    name: 'Tanner Linsley',
    age: 26,
    friend: {
        name: 'Jason Maurer',
        age: 23,
    }
}, "entry2": {
    name: 'aTanner Linsley',
    age: 26,
    friend: {
        name: 'aJason Maurer',
        age: 23,
    }
} };
```

Is this a problem with the structure of my object, or does it simply mean the library does not support the population via objects in this way?

Note: I prefer to maintain this data structure (which will become huge) as an object (dictionary) instead of an array so I can efficiently access elements by key for another use (outside of react-table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `react-table` library would expect an input like that:

```
const data = [{
    name: 'Tanner Linsley',
    age: 26,
    friend: {
        name: 'Jason Maurer',
        age: 23,
    }
},{
    name: 'aTanner Linsley',
    age: 26,
    friend: {
        name: 'aJason Maurer',
        age: 23,
    }
}];
```

> I prefer to maintain this data structure

Is there any particular reason to that? However, if you really want to do it like that, you could apply the `Object.values(...)` ([MDN Source)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) method to your data before passing it to the component. In that case you can manage it as you desire and the component will get the right data structure.

```
const convertedObject = Object.values(data);
```

But keep in mind that in this case, you will lose your keys `entry1` and so on.

Comment: Yes, the benefit of using an object/dict versus an array is faster accesses. data['key']  is faster than data.filter(element => {element.name == name})[0]

Comment: Instead of trying to get users to create array data structures, why not change the documentation to explicitly say "only accepts arrays" for data.